# dynamic asynchronous iframe creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

### dynamic asynchronous iframe creation

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://www.google.com" height="240" width="350"></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Suggest me using javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO is not meant to be a "write my code for me" site - if that's what you are looking for, you should probably hire an expert to do it for you, as this can be quite a big task. If you have a *specific* technical question arising of your working on the issue, feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var node = document.createElement("IFRAME");
node.async = "true";
node.src ="http://www.google.com";
node.width = '300px';
node.height = '400px';
node.frameBorder = "0";
node.scrolling = "NO";
document.body.appendChild(node);
</script>
```

hope it helps !!!